# With evil keybindings, how do I navigate using actual lines only if a count is involved?

Tags: evil, line-numbers

Before moving to Emacs, I had a Vim setup that included the functionality to **navigate between visual lines with `j` and `k` by default, but if there was a count involved (e.g. `20j`), "regular" lines should be used**. This could easily be achieved with the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
nnoremap <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
```

However, I have had trouble implementing this with Evil in Emacs. I have  tried looking up solutions but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `evil-next-line` and `evil-next-visual-line` and combine them as follows:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'evil
  (evil-define-motion evil-next-line (count)
    "Move the cursor COUNT screen lines down."
    :type line
    (let ((line-move-visual (unless count t)))
      (evil-line-move (or count 1))))

  (evil-define-motion evil-previous-line (count)
  "Move the cursor COUNT lines up."
  :type line
  (let ((line-move-visual (unless count t)))
    (evil-line-move (- (or count 1))))))
```

You would just have to make a choice for the `:type`, see [here](https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extension.html#motions) (but I hope that limitation is not critical).

Instead of binding this new command in all evil-states, we just override `evil-next-line` (and load it after evil by wrapping it in a `with-eval-after-load`, see its docstring).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, would this be a correct implementation of this?

```
(with-eval-after-load "evil"
    (evil-define-motion evil-next-line (count)
      "Move the cursor COUNT screen lines down."
      :type line
      (let ((line-move-visual (unless count t))
            (evil-line-move (or count 1))))))
```

With the above code, it does not seem to work, unfortunately, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah sorry, somehow a parenthesis was dropped when copying. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!